# Crash in protobuf after upgrading to Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, protocol-buffers, macos-mojave

After upgrading to Mojave the application started to crash in XCode debugger. It does run normally as a standalone application.

The backtrace looks like the following:

```
frames 0-5 call for the custom new, which is not initialized, the app initializes custom memory allocator in main
frame #6: 0x00007fff53ee006f libprotobuf.dylib`wireless_diagnostics::google::protobuf::(anonymous namespace)::InitGeneratedPool() + 20
frame #7: 0x00007fff53ecdd47 libprotobuf-lite.dylib`wireless_diagnostics::google::protobuf::internal::FunctionClosure0::Run() + 17
frame #8: 0x00007fff53ecdd1b libprotobuf-lite.dylib`wireless_diagnostics::google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl(long*, wireless_diagnostics::google::protobuf::Closure*) + 73
frame #9: 0x00007fff53edffbe libprotobuf.dylib`wireless_diagnostics::google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int) + 78
frame #10: 0x00007fff53edfbf9 libprotobuf.dylib`wireless_diagnostics::google::protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto() + 68
frame #11: 0x0000000117de8cc8 dyld`ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 518
frame #12: 0x0000000117de8ec6 dyld`ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
frame #13: 0x0000000117de40da dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 358
frame #14: 0x0000000117de406d dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 249
frame #15: 0x0000000117de406d dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 249
frame #16: 0x0000000117de406d dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 249
frame #17: 0x0000000117de406d dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 249
frame #18: 0x0000000117de406d dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 249
frame #19: 0x0000000117de3254 dyld`ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 134
frame #20: 0x0000000117de32e8 dyld`ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 74
frame #21: 0x0000000117dd2756 dyld`dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 169
frame #22: 0x0000000117dd778f dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 6237
frame #23: 0x0000000117dd14f6 dyld`dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 1154
frame #24: 0x0000000117dd1036 dyld`_dyld_start + 54
```

Xcode injects the dynamic library libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib, which causes the crash. And problematic *.dylib is

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libprotobuf.dylib
```

Fixing the custom allocator is the one of the options, but I want to avoid doing it.

Do you know any way to prevent XCode from injecting libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib?

Answer (score 0):

It is appeared to be a bug in Mojave. Apple is working on fixing it, but they did not give me any ETA.

For now I fixed the crash by fixing my custom allocator.